# If $|z|<1 $ then $Log(1-z^2)=Log(1-z)+Log(1+z)$ , $ z\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Verify that $Log(1-z^2)=Log(1-z)+Log(1+z)$ when  $|z|<1$.

What can be said about $Log(\frac{1-z}{1+z})$ for such $z$ ?

I tried . But no conclusion.

Here $Log$ is the principal branch.

Comment: $(1-z^2)=(1+z)(1-z)$, $Log(ab)=Log(a)+Log(b)$

Comment: @Tsemo: care must be taken for the complex logarithm.

Comment: $z$ is a complex number.

Comment: Note that if $|z|<1$ then $\operatorname{re} (1 \pm z) >0$, so you have $\operatorname{arg} (1-z^2) = \operatorname{arg} (1-z) + \operatorname{arg} (1+z)$.

Comment: Proof of " If $|z|<1$  then $re(1±z)>0$"

Comment: Draw a circle of radius 1 around 1.

Comment: $Re(1\pm z)=1\pm Re(z)$ and $|z|<1\Rightarrow -1<Re(z)<1$.

Comment: Then what about the circle of radius 1 around -1 ?

Answer (score 3):

without using series

$\text{Log}(1-z)+\text{Log}(1+z)=\ln|1+z|+i\text{Arg}(1+z)+\ln|1-z|+i\text{Arg}(1-z)=\ln|(1+z)(1-z)|+i(\text{Arg}(1+z)+\text{Arg}(1-z))=\ln|1-z^2|+i\text{Arg}(1-z^2)=\text{Log}(1-z^2)$

Answer (score 2):

The Taylor series of $\log{(1-z^2)}, \:\log{(1-z)},\:\log{(1+z)}$ are absolute convergent in $|z|<1$. So
$$
\log{(1-z)}+\log{(1+z)}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n}}{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^{n}}{n}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2n}}{n}=\log{(1-z^2)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

This is an exercise from Conway's "Functions of one complex variable" (Ch. III, Sec. 2, Ex. 20) that gives a sufficient condition for the log of a
product to be the sum of the logs.

Suppose $z_k$ are such that $\operatorname{re} z_1\cdots z_i >0$ for $i=1,...,n$. Then
$ \operatorname{Log} (z_1\cdots z_n) = \operatorname{Log} z_1 + \cdots + \operatorname{Log} z_n$. This is straightforward to establish using the
polar form of $z_k$.

In the above example, if $|z|<1$, then $\operatorname{re} (1-z) >0$,
$\operatorname{re} (1+z) >0$, $\operatorname{re} {1 \over 1+z} >0$, $\operatorname{re} {1-z \over 1+z} >0$
and $\operatorname{re} (1-z^2) >0$.